# Proof-Check: Reasoning correct to apply Jensen $\mathbb E [X^{p}]\leq \mathbb E [X]^{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convex-analysis, expected-value, jensen-inequality

Given some $p \in [0,1]$, and some nonnegative, integrable random variable $X$.  I claim that

$$\mathbb E [X^{p}]\leq \mathbb E [X]^{p}.$$

My line of reasoning:

The map $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R,\; f(x):=x^{p}$, is concave (still working on a proof for this; any ideas?).

If we have concavity of $f$, then we may proceed as follows

$$ \mathbb E[X^{p}]=\mathbb E[f(X)]\leq f(\mathbb E[X])=\mathbb E[X]^{p}.$$

Is my reasoning fine?

Comment: this is correct. $f$ is concave because $f''\le 0$.